# Почему в laravel mix при компиляции scss в css у свойства background-image пропадает нормальная ссылка на изображение?

Tags: css, scss, laravel-mix

Я использую laravel mix чтобы верстать. Есть папка исходников src в которой есть папка с изображениями images (src/images). Пишу scss который тоже лежит в этой папке (src/styles/style.scss), так же есть плагин чтобы копировать картинки из каталога ресурсов в публичный каталог:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

// const SVGSpritemapPlugin = require('svg-spritemap-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
// const ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;
// const imageminMozjpeg = require('imagemin-mozjpeg');

mix.sass('src/styles/style.scss', 'css');

// mix.copyDirectory('src/images', 'images');

mix.setPublicPath('dist');

mix.webpackConfig({

    plugins: [

        // Копируем картинки из каталога ресурсов в публичный каталог

        new CopyWebpackPlugin({

            patterns: [

                {
                    from: 'src/images', // Путь относительно каталога с webpack.mix.js
                    to: 'images', // Путь относительно каталога public/,
                    globOptions: {
                        ignore: ["**/icons/**"], // Игнорируем каталог с иконками
                    },
                },
            ],
        }),

        // Оптимизируем качество изображений

        new ImageminPlugin({
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
            plugins: [
                imageminMozjpeg({
                    quality: 80,
                    progressive: true,
                }),
            ],
        }),
    ],
})
```

Но вся проблема заключается в том что если в папке style.scss указать следующий код:

```
.header{
        background-image: url('../images/main-bg.png');
}
```

то в style.css он попадает в следующем виде:

```
.header {
  background-image: url(/images/main-bg.png?e0532be9422f411efcfdb846b50d969d);
}
```

И соответственно не читается и изображение не подставляется, почему так?

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение , всё дело в том что laravel-mix по умолчанию перезаписывает url, чтобы это отключить нужно написать следующую  команду

```
mix.sass('src/app.scss', 'dist').options({
    processCssUrls: false
});
```

подробнее здесь  https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/url-rewriting